# How to count users group by time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with user id and created_at of type timestamp, I want to count how many users have created their account in 3 hours interval for a given day. so far I have created this query but I'm not able to get the count for each three hours

```
with time_cte AS (
    SELECT time_sample from
            generate_series('2021-12-01'::date, '2021-12-01'::date + interval '1 day', interval '3 hour')
                as time_sample
) SELECT time_sample, count(u.id) FROM time_cte
    join users u ON u.created_at::date = '2021-12-01'::date
                                       GROUP BY time_sample;
```

I am able to get series and count but they are total users count for that day

The output I got

```
time_sample                count
2021-12-01 00:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-01 03:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-01 06:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-01 09:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-01 12:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-01 15:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-01 18:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-01 21:00:00.000000, 4
2021-12-02 00:00:00.000000, 4
```

The output I expect is

```
time_sample                count
2021-12-01 00:00:00.000000, 0
2021-12-01 03:00:00.000000, 0
2021-12-01 06:00:00.000000, 3
2021-12-01 09:00:00.000000, 1
2021-12-01 12:00:00.000000, 0
2021-12-01 15:00:00.000000, 0
2021-12-01 18:00:00.000000, 0
2021-12-01 21:00:00.000000, 0
2021-12-02 00:00:00.000000, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL 14 you can use the built-in [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function.

```sql
select 
  date_bin(interval '3 hours', created_at, date_trunc('day', created_at)) as time_slot,
  count(*) as cnt
from users 
group by time_slot
order by time_slot;
```

For PostgreSQL versions before 14 you may use [this](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/Pre-PG14-date_bin-function) implementation of `date_bin`.